# Karush-Kuhn-Tucker for series

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

Does the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem on sufficient conditions for optimality of a convex program apply in countable dimension?

For precisions, see Definition 4.1.1 and Theorem 4.1.4 of [this course](https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_4.pdf). Does the theorem extend to an infinite (but discrete) number of variables and associated constraints? If so, do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't think "countable dimension" is that useful. Any infinite-dimensional Banach space has uncountable dimension. Actually, the dimension must be at least the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe there exists similar results in uncountable dimension (i.e. for functions instead of series) but that's not the question here, and I am not sure the link between the two is straightforward. The paper presented below works in countable dimension.

Comment: No infinite-dimensional Banach space has countable dimension, that includes spaces of sequences and series. You can see the standard argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of).

Comment: No. What this shows is that no infinite-dimensional Banach space has a countable (Hamel) basis. But there can be a countable Schauder basis. In Bachir et al. (2021), Schauder bases are used on a Banach space of countable dimension.

Comment: "Dimension" refers to the size of a Hamel basis.

Comment: Ah ok. How should I say then?

Comment: Maybe a KKT-theorem for sequence spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the title from "Karush-Kuhn-Tucker in infinite dimension" to "KKT for series".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [Bachir et al. (2021)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s43036-020-00125-y) extend the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem under mild hypotheses, for an infinite number of variables (their Corollary 4.1).

I give hereafter a weaker version of the generalization of Karush-Kuh-Tucker for sequence spaces:

> Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a nonempty convex subset of
> $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and let $x^{*}\in Int\left(X\right)$. Let
> $f,g_{1},g_{2},...,g_{m}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be convex functions
> continuous at $x^{*}$ and term-to-term differentiable at $x^{*}$, i.e.
> such that the functions
> $f_{n,x^{*}}\left(x_{n}\right):=f\left((x_1^{*},...,x_{n-1}^*,x_n,x_{n+1}^*,...)\right)$ and
> $g_{j,n,x^{*}}\left(x_{n}\right):=g_{j}\left((x_1^{*},...,x_{n-1}^*,x_n,x_{n+1}^*,...)\right)$ are
> differentiable at $x_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
> $j\in\left\{ 1,2,...,m\right\}$.
>
> (Qualification condition) Suppose that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$
> and for all $x\in X$,
> $$x^{*}+P^{k}\left(x-x^{*}\right)=\left(x_{1},...,x_{k},x_{k+1}^{*},x_{k+2}^{*},...\right)\in X$$
> If there exist
> $\left(\lambda_{j}^{*}\right)_{j}\in\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$
> such that
>
> $$\lambda_{j}^{*}g_{j}\left(x^{*}\right)  =0,\:\forall j\in\left\{
> 1,2,...,m\right\} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$$
> $$f_{n,x^{*}}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{m}   \lambda_{j}^{*}g_{j,n,x^{*}}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right)=0,\:\forall
> n\in\mathbb{N} \quad \quad (2)$$
>
> (Sufficiency) Then $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution on $\Gamma:=\left\{
> \left(x_{i}\right)_{i}\in
> X\,:\,g_{1}\left(x\right)\leq0,...,g_{m}\left(x\right)\leq0\right\} :$
>
> $$f\left(x^{*}\right)=\underset{x\in\Gamma}{\inf}f\left(x\right)$$
>
> (Necessity) Besides, if $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution on $\Gamma$ and
> if the Slater condition $Int\left(\Gamma\right)\neq\emptyset$ is
> verified, then there exist unique
> $\left(\lambda_{j}^{*}\right)_{j}\in\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$
> which verify the (Karush-Kuhn-Tucker) conditions (1) and (2).

The number of constraints has to be finite, but simple constraints like non-negativity constraints can be replaced by an equivalent restriction on the domain of the variables. For example, instead of the constraints $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\;x_n \geq 0$ on the domain $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, one can take $X=(\mathbb{R}_+)^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the theorem applies.

Note that the (sufficiency) result is easy to prove when one further assumes that the convex Lagrangian $\mathcal L(x, \lambda)=f(x)+\sum_{j=1}^m\lambda_j g_j(x)$ is Gateaux differentiable, with a Gateaux derivative equal to 0 at $u=(x^*, \lambda^*)$.

Indeed, a function $h: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ convex and Gateaux differentiable on $V$ verifies $h(v)-h(u) \geq h^\prime(u; v-u), \forall u,v \in V$, where $h^\prime(u; v)$ is the directional derivative of $h$ at $u$ in the direction $v$. (One can see that from the definition of convexity: $h(u)+\theta \left( h(v) -h(u) \right) \geq h\left(u+\theta (v-u)\right)$; subtracting $h(u)$, dividing by $\theta$, and taking the limit when $\theta \rightarrow 0^+$; see [this](https://math.unice.fr/%7Eauroux/EPU/Optim2.pdf) for more details). Applying that inequality to the Lagrangian at $u$ proves that the Lagrangian admits a minimum at $u$, which solves the minimization program: $ f(x^*) =L(x^*, \lambda^*) \leq f(x)+\sum_{j=1}^m\lambda_j g_j(x) \leq f(x), \; \forall x\in \Gamma$.

However, in general, it is not easy to prove that the Gateaux derivative of a convex series (such as an infinite Lagragian) (exists and) equals 0 at some point $u$, unless one uses the result (Theorem 3.14 in [Bachir et al. (2021)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s43036-020-00125-y)) that the Gateaux derivative is thus equal to the sum of derivatives of each term in the series.